# homestead init not defined

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

While installing homestead following [the official installation instructions of version 4.2](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead), I received the following error message when executing `$ homestead init`:
[image: error message]

i.e.

```
 [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  Command "init" is not defined.
```

My step before that was to install homestead with `composer global require "laravel/homestead=~3.0"`

I installed `Laravel Homestead version 3.0.1` and `homestead` is in my `PATH`.

Comment: I am having this error without homestead. Please help

Comment: @MarthaJames The question is about the command `homestead init` throwing an error. Of course there are other commands with an `init` option. You should probably open an own question with your scenario. By the way: Why did you downvote the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm I remember having this problem when I was first installing homestead. I can see the link you provided is in relation to Laravel 4.2. Following the homestead installation from the 5.2 docs seemed to be fine for myself however:

[Laravel Homestead: Installation & Setup](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead)

Comment: Do you mean the `~/.homestead` directory? That directory does not yet exist. The command `homestead init` should create a file within that directory (and probably also create the directory if it doesn't exist yet.) Also, I believe that the command could be run anywhere because it is my `PATH`.

Comment: @Andrusch Hmmm I remember having this problem when I was first installing homestead. I can see the link you provided is in relation to Laravel 4.2. Following the homestead installation from the 5.1 docs seemed to be fine for myself however: [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead#installation-and-setup)

Comment: Thanks! I followed the instructions in the 5.2 docs since that's the version of Lavarel I have. It then worked out fine. If you please change your answer to include that I will accept it!

Comment: @Andrusch I've changed it now. Thanks, and glad to hear it worked!

Comment: I have no idea why composer global require installation doesn`t work but I followed the documentation and installed Homestead separatedly as well. Working now.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple.
Make sure you have added this to your bash profiel or .zshrc file.

```
function homestead() {
    ( cd ~/Homestead && vagrant $* )
}
```